# Better way to extract numbers from a string

Tags: regex, vb.net, winforms

I have been trying to change a string like this, `{X=5, Y=9}` to a string like this `(5, 9)`, as it would be used as an on-screen coordinate.

I finally came up with this code:

```vb
Dim str As String = String.Empty
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
Dim m As Match = regex.Match("{X=9")
If m.Success Then str = m.Value
Dim s As Match = regex.Match("Y=5}")
If s.Success Then str = "(" & str & ", " & s.Value & ")"
MsgBox(str)
```

which does work, but surely there must be a better way to do this (I not familiar with Regex).

I have many to convert in my program, and doing it like above would be torturous.

Comment: Do you have one `{X=5, Y=9}` string or two `{X=9` and `Y=5}`  strings?

Comment: Ok, let's try a "try-this" approach. Try `Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(input, ".*?=(\d+).*?=(\d+).*", "($1, $2)")`

Comment: You could create a parser, or is that more effort than you're willing to exert?

Comment: Or `dim output = $"({string.Join(", ", Regex.Matches(input, "\d+").OfType(Of Match)().Select(function(m) m.Value))})"`

Comment: Or `dim matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\d+") dim p = new Point(integer.Parse(matches(0).Value), integer.Parse(matches(1).Value))`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor and @Jimi. Works great in a function.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I posted an answer below, please consider accepting when you drop back in here to let others know the solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(input, ".*?=(\d+).*?=(\d+).*", "($1, $2)")
```

The regex means

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than newline chars as few as possible
- `=` - an equals sign
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `.*?=` - any 0+ chars other than newline chars as few as possible and then a `=` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than newline chars as many as possible

The `$1` and `$2` in the replacement pattern are replacement backreferences that point to the values stored in Group 1 and 2 memory buffer.